# How to get one to many relationship hierarchy data in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have below query result set which is getting one to many hierarchy data, but for some reason the result set json list doesn't have parent fields (pid,loc)

Here is the **View Code**

```
res=Can.objects.select_related().all().prefetch_related('ppid__loc')
```

Here are the models :

```
class Cate(models.Model):
    pid=models.IntegerField(unique=True, db_column='pid', primary_key=True)
    loc=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        managed="false"
        db_table="prf"

class Can(models.Model):
    ppid=models.ForeignKey(to=Cate, db_column='ppid')
    sid=models.IntegerField()
    sname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class Meta:
        managed="false"
        db_table="sf"
```

When I apply break points, I can see all the fields but the result set is like this below :

```
[{"sid":1,"sname":"housing",ppid:1},{..},{..}]
```

What am expecting is below:

```
[{"pid":2,"loc":"Bangalore","skills":[{"sid":1,"sname":"housing","ppid":1},{..},{..}]},{"pid":3,"loc":"New York","skills":[{{"sid":1,"sname":"housing","ppid":9},{..}]}]
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: It's hard to get the data structrue by using usual ORM operations. You might try with some api frameworks like `tastypie` or `django-rest-framework`.

Comment: okay, Thank you Shang Wang!.. Thought if it works, I could avoid loops to structure the result..  it would have been helpful if we can achieve from ORM directly.. How complex is it to use tastypie for this one?